# How can I check for existence of Itunes track in Applescript without throwing error

Tags: applescript, itunes

the idea of this script (simplified to show the issue) is checks if a track exists,

```
    tell application "iTunes"
        set matchtrack to get first track in playlist 1 whose persistent ID is "F1A68AD90AA66648"
        if matchtrack is not {} then
            print name of matchtrack
        else
            print "no track found"
        end if
    end tell
```

unfortunately if the track does not exist it gives error

```
"iTunes got an error: Can’t get track 1 of playlist 1 whose persistent ID = \"F1A68AD90AA66648\"." number -1728 from track 1 of playlist 1 whose persistent ID = "F1A68AD90AA66648"
'
```

instead of just printing 'no track found'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get first track` give a track object or an error

`tracks` give a list of one track or an empty list

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set matchtrack to tracks in playlist 1 whose persistent ID is "F1A68AD90AA66648"
    if matchtrack is not {} then
        return name of item 1 of matchtrack
    else
        return "no track found"
    end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would be to use a `try block`, like this:

```
set persistentID to "F1A68AD90AA66648"
tell application "iTunes"
    try
        set matchtrack to get first track in playlist 1 whose persistent ID is persistentID
        if matchtrack is not {} then
            log (get name of matchtrack)
        else
            log "no track found"
        end if
    on error the error_message number the error_number
        log "Error (probably no track found)"
        -- display dialog "Error: " & the error_number & ". " & the error_message buttons {"Cancel"} default button 1
    end try
end tell
```

BTW: use `log` instead of `print` and `(get name of matchtrack)` instead of `(name of matchtrack)`

This would work but goes thru all the tracks in a named playlist:

```
set flagFound to false
set mTrack to ""


# SETUP THOSE FIRST
# -------------------------------------------------------
property Library_Name : "Library" # "Mediathek" in german
property Playlist_Name : "Bob Marley"

set persistentID to "F1A68AD90AA66648"
# -------------------------------------------------------

tell application "iTunes"

    tell source Library_Name
        tell playlist Playlist_Name
            repeat with i from the (count of tracks) to 1 by -1

                if (the persistent ID of track i is persistentID) then
                    set mTrack to track i
                    set flagFound to true
                    exit repeat
                end if

            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell

    if flagFound then

        tell mTrack
            log "Found…"
            log "Name: " & (get name)
            log "persistent ID: " & (get persistent ID)
        end tell

    else

        log "no track with persistent ID " & persistentID & " found"

    end if

end tell
```

Comment: Ok I get you, but in your example the line 'log "no track found"' will never be called will it because will always give error if track not found ?

Comment: Yes, of course, that's why we have the on error - part where it gets logged

Comment: but whats the point of the else stement ? I would prefer a solution that could check in a way that didnt have to throw an error.

Comment: the else statement is left from your code which I just wrapped into a try block but in the case iTunes stops to throw such errors, it comes in handy and it should stay there  | -  see addition for another approach.

Comment: Its absolutely normal to use a try block to prevent that a script won't stop with an error dialog. It won't change anything how the script runs, it will run just the same way.  AppleScript isn't very similar to other languages when it comes to words like "try".

Comment: @PaulTaylor Cool, jackjr300 has the answer.